# Active selector CSS not working properly for iOS 8.2, 8.3, 8.1.3 , and iOS 8.4.1

Tags: ios, css, safari

I tried to apply the CSS property on a div in the following way:

```
#mob: active {
   color: rgb(222, 21, 17);
}
```

Notice the space before active. If I remove it, it works fine for Android and all IOS versions on mobile. But if I keep the extra space many of the other clickable divs in the page become non-clickable for many IOS versions like  8.2, 8.3, 8.1.3 , and 8.4.1 (the color change on div being active still works)

I just want to know the root cause of this issue.

Comment: `#mob: active` is not a valid selector. I'd be surprised if it worked *anywhere* at all.

Comment: I checked it on Chrome and firefox and it works perfectly with space. I just tried it on the add comment button below by making it display to none on active state and it works !

Comment: There's absolutely no way it could work with a space there unless both browsers happen to be affected by exactly the same bug to the same extent. It sounds like a caching issue more than anything. Either those browsers aren't seeing the invalid selector, or they're applying a different rule entirely.

Comment: My bad, I meant to ask the behavior where space is before the colon, not after it

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I think its not an issue, the css selector is applied to the child element. If you chage `a:active` to `p: active` in this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more1) it works.

Comment: I checked it on Chrome and firefox and it works perfectly with space

Comment: Interesting, in what platform?... I'm using Linux on a PC. May be you should try editing this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more1).

Comment: Im using chrome on mac 10.9.5 . and I tried removing the add comment button by applying the css :

form#add-comment-32276383 :active {
    display: none;
}
 
and it works

Comment: Chrome version: Version 44.0.2403.157

Comment: Now in windows 8.1 Firefox 40.0.2  and IE 11.0.96 and doesn't work with `a: active` or `a :active`

Comment: I try what you say... If you apply that selector to the container it works, in this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more1) if you change to `p :active` it works, may be the browser is applying that rule to the child of the <div> that is an <a> tag... Normally you use a space to select a child. But it is strange

Comment: Your assumption is correct. It may look strange, but it's perfectly acceptable for a pseudo-class to stand on its own, with its `:` at the beginning. What's *not* valid is `p: active`, where the space appears *after* the `:`. I maintain that there's no way the latter could ever work in any browser.

Comment: My bad, I meant to ask the behavior where space is before the colon, not after it